# React TypeError: orders.map is not a function

Tags: react-redux

I'm a begginer in React. I'm trying to fetch an array of data about orders and that is working and then map it to display specific information about each order.
I'm getting TypeError: orders.map is not a function exception in my application.
Here's my code:

```
class Orders extends Component {
state = {
  orders: []
};
componentDidMount() {

  axios
    .get("https://localhost:9090/orders")
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ orders: res.data });
      console.log(res.data);
    });
}

render() {
  const { orders } = this.state;
  const orderList =
    this.state.orders.length > 0 ? (
      orders.map(o => {
        return (
          <div key={o.orderId}>
           <p>
                {o.isbn} 
                </p>
              </div>

        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div className="row p-5 m-5">
        <div className="offset-sm-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
          <span className="text-grey r">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return <div className="container">{orderList}</div>;
}}
```

What's interesting, I have a similar code, that is working. The only difference is basically what it's fetching. Here's the code:

```
class BookList extends Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.match.params.search_term);

axios
  .get("https://localhost:8080/search?searchTerm=" + search_term)
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({ books: res.data });
    console.log(res.data);
  });
  }
render() {
const { books } = this.state;
const booksList =
  this.state.books.length > 0 ? (
    books.map(b => {
      return (
        <div key={b.isbn} className="card">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">
              <Link to={"/details/" + b.isbn}>{b.title}</Link>
            </h5>

            <div className="card-subtitle text-muted">
              {b.author} ({b.year}) /{" "}
              <span className=" text-danger">{b.category}</span>
            </div>
            <p />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <div className="row p-5 m-5">
      <div className="offset-sm-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
        <span className="text-grey r">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
return <div className="container">{booksList}</div>;
}}
```

I can't find the difference that would cause that exception. It is an array in both cases.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
here's the output of response data:
[response data of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drUQ0.png)
[response data of bokstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcZTA.png)

Comment: Dani, does one return an object that has an array in it? eg. `{[1,2,3]}`. Please share with us the output of both when you use `console.log()` before the map function.

Answer (score 1):

From them images it looks like the ***orders*** are processed as plain text and not parsed to JSON. Check that your back-end specifies the required headers `Content-Type: application/json` so that `axios` will parse the data correctly.

Alternatively you could parse the text client-side with `JSON.parse(res.data)`